# How to add dynamic header to the request send from react app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication

I am passing cookie details from the react like the following way:

```
export const userAuthStatus = async () => {
 let authStatus = [];
 authStatus = axios.post('https://../auth_status', { resources: [{ classpath: 'test }] },
  { withCredentials: true }).then(response => response.data.user);

  return authStatus;
};
```

And my backend service has been written in Springboot. I am getting the cookie(origin) in my spring boot application using the following code.

```
   request.getHeader("origin")
```

But I need to add a particular cookie value as a header in a request.

```
  curl -X GET "http://.../authstatus" -H "origin:"value"
```

But now I am getting like curl -X GET "http://.../authstatus" -H "accept: */*"

Here I have added the following CORSFilter

```
@Component
```

@Configuration
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{

```
String authStatusCheckUrl = "https://..../autthenticate";
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String origin = request.getHeader("origin");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization, content-type, xsrf-token, X-Auth-Token, X-App-Token, X-App-Version, X-App-Env");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
    if (origin != null)
    {
        HttpStatus statuscode = AuthController.checkUserAuth(request.getHeader("origin"), authStatusCheckUrl);
        if(statuscode.equals(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)){
            response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", request.getHeader("at_origin"));
        }
    }
    else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    }

 }
```

How can add a header for each request sent from react. (In react, I can't specify the Header, I have to send only {withCredentials:true} but while doing the request I need to add a specific header

Answer (score 0):

You can create apiClient in separate module and then import them anywhere you want.

```js
//apiClient
const apiClient = (headers) => axios.create({
  headers
});

export default apiClient
```

```js
//other file
import apiClient from "./apiClient"

const headers = {
    "Header-Common": "abc"
}

apiClient(headers).post(
    'https://../auth_status', 
    { resources: [{ classpath: 'test' }] },
    { withCredentials: true }
).then(response => response.data.user);
};
```

And thanks for this instance of axios all your request will be send with "Header-Common" or any other which you specified. If your request have other common parameters ( e.g withCredentials ) you can set them inside apiClient .

Comment: Thanks but  the header value is dynamic. I can't set it hardcoded

Comment: Or you can write axios.post("uri", { /* data */ }, { withCridentials: true, headers: { /* headers here */ } }) then you don't need to create external module.

Comment: Sorry, but "Header-Common" value is very dynamic. It's basically a session id